# How do I import a CSV file in R?

Tags: r, csv, import

I have a `.csv` file in my workstation. How can I open that file in R and do statistical calculation?

Comment: have a look at the [R Data Import Export](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-data.pdf) manual

Answer (score 195, accepted):

You would use the `read.csv` function; for example:

```
dat = read.csv("spam.csv", header = TRUE)
```

You can also reference [this tutorial](http://www.cyclismo.org/tutorial/R/input.html#read) for more details.

**Note:** make sure the `.csv` file to read is in your working directory (using  `getwd()`) or specify the right path to file. If you want, you can set the current directory using [`setwd`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.3/topics/getwd).