# Cannot read in .csv file into R Studio - error message?

Tags: rstudio

Completely new to R (being introduced to it in a class right now).

I'm having some issues just getting my data to read in. I'm sourcing it from a webpage: (ftp://webftp.vancouver.ca/opendata/csv/crime_2004.csv) and putting both the URL and the file path if I download the .csv file is giving me the following error message:

```
"Error in open.connection(file, "rt") : 
  URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL"
```

My code:

```
fname = curl("/Users/shane_1001/Downloads/crime_2004.csv")
data = read.csv(fname, header=T)
print(head(data))
```

Comment: I would say you should put the ftp-link into curl and not a path to your diskdrive. Or if you need to address the file locally you should create a file:// -link

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried that too but it's giving me a similar error message: 

Error in open.connection(file, "rt") : 
  FTP: couldn't retrieve (RETR failed) the specified file

Comment: Tried the search ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13265153/how-to-import-a-csv-file