# Open csv in R, type double

Tags: r

I want to open a csv that has 5 columns, three of them have values ​​with three decimals and when I try to open it with "read.csv", one of them opens it with a decimal, another with none and the other with the three, like this:

```
             V1      V2      V3  V4  V5
1      377946.8 4109939 687.679 -89  15
2      377946.8 4109939 687.678 -89  23
3      377946.8 4109939 687.676 -89 123
4      377946.8 4109939 687.697 -89  84
5      377946.8 4109939 687.687 -89  30
6      377946.8 4109939 687.661 -89  46
```

can someone tell me what is the problem and the solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I import a CSV file in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13265153/how-do-i-import-a-csv-file-in-r)

Comment: How should it look like? (i.e. what is your problem) Did you control with `df$V1` ... ? See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287616/controlling-number-of-decimal-digits-in-print-output-in-r

Comment: Have you tried other readers such as read.table and fread?